# redirect from /members/front to /members/custom

Tags: dashboard, buddypress, members

Im not trying to redirect user while logging in, thats already done. I want everybody, logged or not-logged in, to being redirected from members homepage/dashboard where I can see now 'Latest updates' to another custom tab, but lets say to Friends.

Whats the best way to achive it? because i cant find similar problem and missing something when i try by myself. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this did the trick. it doesnt need to redirect, but just changes landing page.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54068617/custom-buddypress-profile-page-set-as-landing-page-bp-default-component